# Moving vertex to the X/Y intersection of two others

Tags: vertices, transforms

I am trying to find the fastest and easiest way to move the selected vertex in the screenshot below to the exact X/Y intersection of the two vertices closest to it.

[image: vertices in blender]

I drew the blue and green lines in to indicate what I'm trying to do.

[image: expected result]

The only way I know of is to:

1. Select the top vertex, copy its X position and paste it into the X position for the target vertex.
2. Repeat above with the bottom vertex, except with Y position.

This works, but it's slow (even with Blender's great feature where you can copy and paste without the text fields having focus).

Is there a better way? I tried to mess around with snapping but couldn't make it work.

Comment: Why? What's the context? What are you trying to do? Is this only for a plane aligned to the global axes?

Comment: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2387/can-a-punishment-be-implemented-for-using-the-word-vertice-in-a-q-a?r=SearchResults&s=1|22.0547  (Esp for @lemon)

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys I'm recreating a building based on a satellite image by starting off with the roof. I'm using a plane and I'm at a section of the building where the walls go in and meet each other, as pictured in the second image. batFINGER, hah, thanks. I'll fix that. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Snapping does work, but it has to be in 2 constrained moves, I think.

- Snap set to 'Vertex' and 'Active'
- <kbd>G</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd>, and then <kbd>G</kbd> <kbd>Y</kbd> to the relevant vertices, with the snap active.

The first move could be <kbd>G</kbd> <kbd>G</kbd>, a slide, no snap, as far as it will go.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In this case I can't see a difference in snapping behaviour between the default "Closest" target and "Active"; both work for me. I didn't know about the G G trick... that could be useful.

Comment: @Mitch In this case, there probably is no difference - 'Closest' takes you to the closest target _before_ the move, not continuously during it. I just have my snap set to Vertex (which is the static target) and Active (the moving source element, edge, vertex, or face) the vast majority of the time..I find it gives me the most specific control.

Answer (score 0):

Use the snapping magnet.
Assuming you're using Blender 2.8+ it's at the top middle of your screen:

[image]

Then click the little downwards facing arrows next to the magnet icon, select Edge / Vertex from the menu:

[image]

Now click the magnet icon so it becomes blue (<kbd>Shift + Tab</kbd> to toggle quickly):

[image]

Now move the smaller cube and with your mouse hover over the edge / vertex(depending on what snapping mode you selected) of the bigger cube you want it to intersect with and it should snap. If only one edge snaps simply move the cube along the axis of the other edge until it also snaps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't understand what you mean by smaller cube and bigger cube.

Comment: [These cubes](https://i.imgur.com/yB6Y7kK.png). But that's really not the point of the answer, basically use the snapping tool, if you don't understand what it is or how to use it from my and Robin's explanations then look it up.

Comment: It's all one mesh, I just drew those green and blue lines in to indicate what I was trying to do. I will update the question to make that more clear.

Comment: Snapping to vertex should still work there, snap it to the z axis of the lower vert(the one on the lower right) then snap it to the x axis of the higher vert.